# LocalDate: parse MM-yyyy

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-8, java-time

I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` after attempt to do following:

```
LocalDate.parse( "09-2017" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy") )
```

What is wrong? Is there any utility in Java to check dateString formats?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A `LocalDate` needs the day, month and year to be built. Your input has only the month and year. You'll have to choose an arbitrary day and set it to the parsed object to create a `LocalDate`.

You can either parse it to a `java.time.YearMonth`, and then choose the day:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy");
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse("09-2017", fmt);
LocalDate dt = ym.atDay(1); // choose whatever day you want
```

Or you can use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with a `java.time.temporal.ChronoField` to define a default value for the day:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // month-year
    .appendPattern("MM-yyyy")
    // default value for day
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse("09-2017", fmt);
```

---

**PS:** If you just want to check if the input is correct, just parsing it to a `YearMonth` is enough (it already checks if the parsed values are valid).